# Rails Model Method Works on Localhost but Not Production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a (fairly simple) method to set a `chapter.sort` field in my app.  Basically a `story` `has_many` `chapters`, and it's a legacy codebase so I'm trying to populate a `sort` column from the existing `created_at` dates.

Here's the method from `story.rb`:

```
def set_chapter_order
  chapters = Chapter.where(story_id: id)
  n = 1
  chapters.order("created_at").each do |c|
    c.update(sort: n)
    c.save
    n += 1
  end
end
```

It works exactly expected on `localhost` when I do the following in my `rails c`:

```
s = Story.all
s.find_each(&:set_chapter_order)
```

In a test `story` the six chapters have `sort`s from 1 to 6.

....but on Heroku I do the exact same thing in the console, and the sample story's chapters come out with `sort`s 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5 or some other strange numbers.

Here's a sample from my `heroku run rails c`:

```
irb(main):002:1* Story.find(1).chapters.each do |c|
irb(main):003:1*   puts  c.sort
irb(main):004:1* end
1
1
1
1
1
2
```

Why is this method working differently (wrong) in a production environment?

Comment: Can you please show the console from production where you see the weird numbers for the sort field.

Comment: @smathy Added!  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Ok, so digging little by little here. Why are you using the association to read the values, but a `Chapter.where(story_id: id)` in your write? Also, any before/after callbacks in your `Chapter` model?

Comment: @smathy You were on the right track with the before/after callbacks in the chapter model.  I did have one that may have conflicted.  After I removed that it still didn't work, but when I also shifted it to an `each_with_index` instead of using `n` it actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

There ended up being two issues that *could* have contributed to the problem.

First, I had a conflicting `before_save` model that dealt with sort in my chapter models.

Second, for some reason it didn't like my using an `n` counter, but it worked with an `each_with_index` loop.

Here's the method that ended up working:

```
def set_chapter_order
  chapters = Chapter.where(story_id: id)
  chapters.order("created_at").each_with_index do |c, index|
    c.update(sort: index + 1)
    c.save
  end
end
```